# How to use pino-pretty on frontend

Tags: logging, pino

I am testing pino for a frontend application (VueJs). I would like to use `pino-pretty` to format the log in console. However, when I import `pino-pretty` it gives errors:

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'process' has already been declared
```